# Redirect doesn't work inside Switch when Fragment has been used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

### Version

`"react-router": "5.0.1",`

### Test Case

```
<Switch>
    <Route
        component={TestComponent}
        key={TestComponentPath}
        path={TestComponentPath}
        exact
    />
    {
        exampleCondition && (
            <>
                 <Route
                    component={TestComponent2}
                    key={TestComponentPath2}
                    path={TestComponentPath2}
                    exact
                 />
                 <Route
                    component={TestComponent3}
                    key={TestComponentPath3}
                    path={TestComponentPath3}
                    exact
                 />
            </>
        )
    }
    <Redirect to={redirectUrl} />
</Switch>
```

### Steps to reproduce

Showed example `Switch`, `Redirect` use case.

### Expected Behavior

Should redirect to the given `redirectUrl` path if no path is matched.

### Actual Behavior

Acts like no `Redirect` has been provided at the end of switch. Problem is probably caused by `React.Fragment` that has been used inside `Switch`. Redirection works fine when it's removed.

### Example sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-tklng

Comment: What do you mean by "redirection works when it's removed" ? If you have no `Redirect` and that the current path does not match the path of any routes, you should display nothing.

Comment: Switch only renders a single matching route or redirect, is your code already matching a route? Can you share a codesandbox (or similar) sample that reproduces your issue?

Comment: If no paths match, then I redirect to proper route that I have in my application. From the example above you can see that I use React.Fragment just to dynamically load routes. In that case redirect doesn't work. But, if  I remove React.Fragment and just return one Route component everything works fine.

Comment: You're actually using the Fragment shorthand, which I've found to be not very useable, have you tried using `<Fragment>...</Fragment>`?

Comment: Yes, have tried. Same affect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> All children of a `<Switch>` should be `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` elements.
>   Only the first child to match the current location will be rendered.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch/children-node

Because you are using Fragment, you are adding additional child that is not supported by `Switch` thus your code dont render.

you should switch your code as below which adds conditional route without using fragment:

```
<Switch>
    <Route
        component={TestComponent}
        key={TestComponentPath}
        path={TestComponentPath}
        exact
    />
    { exampleCondition &&
                 <Route
                    component={TestComponent2}
                    key={TestComponentPath2}
                    path={TestComponentPath2}
                    exact
                 /> }
    { exampleCondition &&
                  <Route
                    component={TestComponent3}
                    key={TestComponentPath3}
                    path={TestComponentPath3}
                    exact
                 /> }
    <Redirect to={redirectUrl} />
</Switch>
```

If you are worrying about repeating code you can add additional layer in your `Route` somewhat like below:

```
<Switch>
    <Route
        component={TestComponent}
        key={TestComponentPath}
        path={TestComponentPath}
        exact
    />
   {someCondition && [
            <Route
              component={TestComponent2}
              key={TestComponentPath2}
              path={TestComponentPath2}
              exact
            />,
            <Route
              component={TestComponent3}
              key={TestComponentPath3}
              path={TestComponentPath3}
              exact
            />
    ]}
    <Redirect to={redirectUrl} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I think this doesn't look that nice if you have more than 2 conditional routes :/

Comment: you can have additional layer if you are worried about repeating code, I'll update my answer. I have mostly used Route with path defined, see if that works for you

Comment: Nesting Switches are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of a `<ProtectedRoute>` component:

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

class ProtectedRoute extends Component<any> {
  render() {
    const { component: Component, allow, ...props } = this.props;
    if (!allow) {
      return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/signin' }} />;
    }
    return <Route {...props} render={(props) => <Component {...props} />} />;
  }
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Then use it like below:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path={yourRootPath} component={App} exact>
    <Route path="home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />

    <ProtectedRoute path="inbox" component={Inbox} allow={this.props.mail} />
    <ProtectedRoute path="contacts" component={Contacts} allow={this.props.mail} />

  </Route>
</Router>
```

---

> I tried using array as the accepted answer suggests, but didn't work
> because **JSX expressions must have one parent element** (maybe this
> used to work in older React versions), also I didn't want to repeat
> code.